# Shadow below Action Bar is not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` with `windowActionBarOverlay` set to true and `windowcontentoverlay` is set with a drawable for shadow. But the shadow is not showing in it. If I change `windowActionBarOverlay` to false shadow will be shown. Here is the code which I am using

`<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowcontentoverlay">@drawable/tab_drop_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomButtonStyle</item>
 </style>`

I want the `windowActionBarOverlay`value should be set to true and need to show the shadow as well.
If anybody have some workaround for this please help me.

Comment: Have you found a way to do it?